# Show Xbox Live Online Status?

Tags: live, xbox360, xbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET XBox Live Account API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564692/net-xbox-live-account-api)

I'm looking into how to get a Xbox Live member's presence (i.e. Not Online, Online playing _).

The only way is to be signed into Xbox.com, visit the player's page, and scrape some text from a div. http://live.xbox.com:80/en-US/MyXbox/Profile?gamertag=example Seen here:

```
<div id="CurrentActivity">
     Call of Duty Black Ops - In Combat Training on Summit
</div>
```

Is there a way to sign into http://xbox.com with a script or otherwise find a player's current status?

Xbox Live does have an API, but it's not an option due to it's very hard to get in.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that the API is the only way to go.  The reason why Microsoft do this, is that it is a security issue for its customers if you can know who is or is not signed in - so you need to go in via the API which complies with the customers privacy settings.